# Java-Writing huge file using Byteoutputstream

Tags: java

I am trying to write a file of size in between 1kb to 10GB using `ByteArrayOutputStream` but the below exception is thrown. I am using jdk 6. Please suggest any better high performance Api. I am using same network box to read and write.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:   Requested array size exceeds VM limit
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at
```

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class PrepareFile {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new PrepareFile().constructFile("f:\\hello","f:\\output",10000000);

    }

    //Writes a large file of 10 GB using input file data of small size by duplicating
    public void constructFile(String fileName, String outPath, int multiplier) throws Exception {
        BufferedOutputStream fos = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        final File inputFile = new File(fileName);
        String path = inputFile.getParent();
        if (outPath != null && !outPath.isEmpty()) {
            path = outPath;
        }

        fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);

        try {



            // read the transactions in the input file.
            byte[] txnData = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
            fis.read(txnData);

            final File outFile = new File(path, "Myfile");
            fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile));
            final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final ByteArrayOutputStream baos1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            //multiplier if input file size is 1 KB and output file is 10 GB, then multiplier value is (1024*1024)

            for (long i = 1; i <= multiplier; i++) {

                if(i >=40000 && i % 40000==0){
                    System.out.println("i value now: "+i);
                    baos.writeTo(fos);
                    baos.reset();
                    //baos.write(txnData);
                }

                // write transactions
                baos.write(txnData);
                baos1.write(txnData); //Exception is coming at this line
            }

            int Padding = myCustomMethod(baos1.toByteArray());

            // write all out data to the output stream
            baos.writeTo(fos);

            baos.flush();
            baos1.flush();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
        }

    }

    public int myCustomMethod(byte[] b){

        //Need complete bytes to prepare the file trailer
        return 0;
    }


}
```

Comment: *Why* are you writing 10Gb to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`? Nobody can suggest something "better" if you don't tell the reason you're doing something. It looks like you just shouldn't be using the ByteArrayOutputStream at all, why not write directly to your intended target instead of to memory?

Comment: You don't have enough memory. Use a different technique, such as *writing to a file*.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Please show some code to know what is the problem and how could we help  you?

Comment: @susanta you can have a look in nio package which is in java 7.x and more

Comment: Here is the sudo code:

Answer (score 3):

You can't have buffer of 2 GB or more in a `ByteArrayOutputStream` as the size is 32-bit signed.

If you want performance I would process the file progressively and avoid such large memory copies as they are really expensive.

BTW I have a library [Chronicle Bytes](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes) which support buffers larger than 2 GB, and can be use native memory and mapped to files to avoid using the heap and can be larger than main memory.

However, if you process the data progressively you won't need such a large buffer.

I also suggest you use Java 8 as it performs 64-bit operations better than Java 6 (which was released ten years ago)

---

EDIT Based on your code, there is no need to use ByteArrayOutputStream and you can prepare the file progressively.

```
//Writes a large file of 10 GB using input file data of small size by duplicating
public void constructFile(String fileName, String outFileName, int multiplier) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes;
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName)) {
        bytes = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(bytes);
    }

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFileName)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < multiplier; i++) {
            fos.write(bytes);
        }
    }

    // now process the file "outFileName"
    // how depends on what you are trying to do.
    // NOTE: It is entirely possible the file should be processed as it is written.
}
```

Comment: Can you please go through the code snippet I have copied and suggest how I can use Chronicle Bytes to prepare a 10 GB file ?

Comment: I will add a simple example but it rather depends on what you need to do with it. Can you say what processing you need done?

Comment: @Susanta added an example based on the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Although extreme, you can make a Super ByteArrayOutputStream which hides several ByteArrayOutputStreams inside (the example below uses 3 of them with maximum capacity 6 GB):

```
public class LargeByteArrayOutputOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private DirectByteArrayOutputStream b1 = new DirectByteArrayOutputStream(Integer.MAX_VALUE -8);
    private DirectByteArrayOutputStream b2 = new DirectByteArrayOutputStream(Integer.MAX_VALUE -8);
    private DirectByteArrayOutputStream b3 = new DirectByteArrayOutputStream(Integer.MAX_VALUE -8);

    private long posWrite = 0;
    private long posRead = 0;
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        if (posWrite < b1.getArray().length) {
            b1.write(b);
        } else if (posWrite < ((long)b1.getArray().length + (long)b2.getArray().length)) {
            b2.write(b);
        } else {
            b3.write(b);
        }
        
        posWrite++;

    }
    
    public long length() {
        return posWrite;
    }

    /** Propably you may want to read afterward */      
    public int read() throws IOException 
    {
        if (posRead > posWrite) {
            return (int)-1;
        } else {
            byte b = 0;
            if (posRead < b1.getArray().length) {
                b = b1.getArray()[(int)posRead];
            } else if (posRead < ((long)b1.getArray().length + (long)b2.getArray().length)) {
                b = b2.getArray()[(int)(posRead - b1.getArray().length)];
            } else {
                b = b3.getArray()[(int)(posRead - ((long)b1.getArray().length + (long)b2.getArray().length))];
            }
            
            posRead++;
            return b;
        }
    }       
}


public class DirectByteArrayOutputStream extends java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream {

 public DirectByteArrayOutputStream(int size) {
   super(size);
 }

 /**
 * Reference to the byte array that backs this buffer.
 */
 public byte[] getArray() {
   return buf;
 }       

 protected void finalize() throws Throwable
 {
  super.finalize();
 }
}
```